# Survival Analysis - finding the survival function from hazard function

Tags: statistics, random-variables, actuarial-science

If the hazard function (i.e the instantaneous rate of death/failure) was given as, for a random survival time:

$h(t) = λ(2 + 2 \exp(−λt))$ for all $t > 0$,

how could find the survival function $S(t)$? Can anyone guide me? Thanks.

Comment: It's a matter of definitions. Do you have the definitions of the hazard function and the survival function? [See the wikipedia definitions and link between the two.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis#Hazard_function_and_cumulative_hazard_function)